# Take words from one file, find it in second and if found write whole line in third file using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io

I want to compare two files, one have a list of index, second file have index, following its content. (see example of my files and desired output) I want to write a code so that it will check line by line for word from first file in second file and if found it will write that full line in third file.

---

**File one:** (file contain just index)

```
CHEA B C13279
CHEA B C13281
CHEA B C13305
CHEA B C14782
CHEA B C15292
CHEA B C15296
CHEA B C15298
CHEA B C15324
CHEA B C15406
CHEA B C15409
```

---

**File two:** (file contain index and content)

```
('CHEA B C13279', 'CHE', 'CHK', '0', 0),
('CHEA B C13281', 'CHE', 'CHK', '0', 0),
('CHEA B C13305', 'CHE', 'CEM', '491', 0),
('CHEA B C14782', 'PHY', 'EI', '17/15', 0),
('CHEA B C15292', 'CHE', 'IEM', '767', 0),
('CHEA B C15296', 'CHE', 'IEM', '767', 0),
('CHEA B C15298', 'CHE', 'IEM', '767', 0),
('CHEA B C15324', 'CHE', 'IEM', '767', 0),
('CHEA B C15406', 'CHE', 'IEM', '769', 0),
('CHEA B C15409', 'CHE', 'IEM', '769', 0),
('CHEA B C15568', 'CHE', 'Elo', '3', 0),
('CHEA B C15571', 'CHE', 'Elo', '0234', 0),
('CHEA B C15575', 'CHE', 'Elo', '0526', 0),
('CHEA B C15577', 'CHE', 'Elo', '260', 0),
('CHEA B C15583', 'CHE', 'Elo','340', 0),
('CHEA B C15587', 'CHE', 'Elo','63', 0),
('CHEA B C15590', 'CHE', 'Elo','325', 0),
('CHEA B C15592', 'CHE', 'Elo','066', 0),
('CHEA B C15599', 'CHE', 'Elo','536', 0);
```

---

**My Code**

```
def findLineByIndex():
    count = 0

    readindexFile = open(indexFilename, 'r')
    readdataFile = open(datafile, 'r').readlines()

    for index in readindexFile:
        if index[2:index.find(2:index[2:].find('\'')+2)] in readdataFile:
            count += 1
            print line

    print count, ""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    findLineByIndex()
```

---

**Result**, I am looking for in **Third file**:

```
('CHEA B C13279', 'CHE', 'CHK', '0', 0),
('CHEA B C13281', 'CHE', 'CHK', '0', 0),
('CHEA B C13305', 'CHE', 'CEM', '491', 0),
('CHEA B C14782', 'PHY', 'EI', '17/15', 0),
('CHEA B C15292', 'CHE', 'IEM', '767', 0),
('CHEA B C15296', 'CHE', 'IEM', '767', 0),
('CHEA B C15298', 'CHE', 'IEM', '767', 0),
('CHEA B C15324', 'CHE', 'IEM', '767', 0),
('CHEA B C15406', 'CHE', 'IEM', '769', 0),
('CHEA B C15409', 'CHE', 'IEM', '769', 0),
```

Comment: Is that really what `file 2` looks like? Is it really a dump of python tuples?

Comment: yes you can say that. tuples containing strings and int values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative way that has time complexity O(n). Other likely solutions will probably be O(n^2) - you will notice the difference on large inputs.

```
with open('file2') as file2:
    file2_dict = {line.split(',')[0].strip("'(") : line for line in file2}

with open('file1') as file1, open('output', 'w') as output:
    for key in file1:
        file2_line = file2_dict.get(key.strip())
        if file2_line is not None:
            output.write(file2_line)
```

First, a dictionary is constructed from the contents of `file2`. The dictionary key is the first element of the tuple (which corresponds to the values in `file1`). The value is the line itself.

Then iterate over the keys from `file1` and look up the dictionary for the key. If found write it to the output file. The result will be:

```
('CHEA B C13279', 'CHE', 'CHK', '0', 0),
('CHEA B C13281', 'CHE', 'CHK', '0', 0),
('CHEA B C13305', 'CHE', 'CEM', '491', 0),
('CHEA B C14782', 'PHY', 'EI', '17/15', 0),
('CHEA B C15292', 'CHE', 'IEM', '767', 0),
('CHEA B C15296', 'CHE', 'IEM', '767', 0),
('CHEA B C15298', 'CHE', 'IEM', '767', 0),
('CHEA B C15324', 'CHE', 'IEM', '767', 0),
('CHEA B C15406', 'CHE', 'IEM', '769', 0),
('CHEA B C15409', 'CHE', 'IEM', '769', 0),
```

The above method assumes that each line is unique for each key. If there can be different lines with the same key, then a `defaultdict` of lists can be used:

```
from collections import defaultdict

file2_dict = defaultdict(list)

with open('file2') as file2:
    for line in file2:
        key = line.split(',')[0].strip("'(")
        file2_dict[key].append(line)

with open('file1') as file1, open('output', 'w') as output:
    for key in file1:
        file2_lines = file2_dict.get(key.strip())
        if file2_lines is not None:
            output.writelines(file2_lines)
```

Now each key maps to a *list* of matching lines, and all lines are output.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution.  It assumes the files should be named file1, file2, and file3.

```
with open('file1') as f:
    file1_text = f.readlines()
with open('file2') as f:
    file2_text = f.readlines()
with open('file3', 'w') as out:
    for line1 in file1_text:
        line1 = line1.rstrip()
        for line2 in file2_text:
            if line1 in line2:
                out.write(line2)
```

Comment: I have 50810 entries in `file2` and 32038 index in `file1`, it should give me 32038 entries from `file2` in `file3` but it skipped some of it, it just wrote **31407**, what does `line1.rstrip()` do ?

Comment: rstrip removes whitespace at the end of the line,  effectively removing the newline character.  This should never cause it to miss something.

Are you certain your whitespace is the same etc?  Your file2 would be much easier to process as a comma delimited file rather than keeping it as python tuple-ish things.

Comment: What if I want to skip those lines similar to indexes and create another file? I tried added `not` in `if` loop and also tried adding `else` But it create a huge file of about 440 GB in about 15 mins. I couldn't able to open it in any of text editor to see.

Comment: You need to strongly reconsider what you are doing on a basic level.  Your can use a regular expression to match the first quote of file 2 and use rstrip with the line in file 1...if they are a match,  this is the most robust way to do it...Technically you should be overmatching possibly right now,  not under matching.

Comment: You are getting massive files because each comparison is outputting to the file...instead you should keep track for each line1 if you have matched it with a True/False...If after the line2 loop you haven't matched,  then output to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Since the readlines() function returns a list, you need to go through all those entries and check if index is in.

```
for index in readindexFile:
    for entry in readdataFile:
        if index in entry:
            count += 1
            <write_entry>
```